# Ошибка при запуске теста

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testng, jest

Запускаю тест и выдает ошибку

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'background' of undefined

   6 | componentDidMount() {
   7 |     const element = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)
>  8 |     element.style.background = 'grey'
     |     ^
   9 |   }
```

Код компонента очень прост:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

class Link extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    const element = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)
    element.style.background = 'grey'
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Link">
        test link
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Link;
```

Код теста:

```
import React from 'react';
import Link from './Link';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

it('renders correctly', () => {
  const tree = renderer
    .create(<Link />)
    .toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Тестирую jest'ом как я понял он не может получить доступ к свойствам dom элемента, как это мне пофиксить кроме способа который указал ниже

> element.style && (element.style.background = 'gray')

Comment: эмммм вообще то ссылки не так указываются

Comment: нашел такое решение: jest.mock('react-dom', () => ({
    findDOMNode: () => ({style: {background:''}}),
}));

Comment: это тестовый компонент просто такое наименование в этом компоненте другая логика, просто я вырезал оттуда все лишнее